# How to remove whitespace from cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, whitespace

I have a large spreadsheet with a ton of cells that appear to be blank but some contain spaces and others contain tabs. Is there a formula to remove this white space so it will result in a blank cell?

Comment: Look into `TRIM()` and `CLEAN()`

Comment: How could I use find and replace to do this?

Comment: trim and clean still left me with whitespace. It seems like it is only removing certain ascii characters...

Comment: Then figure out the CODE() of what is left and use SUBSTITUTE() to substitute that code with `""`